# Maven Spring-Boot: Problems running REST api

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I'm using both **Spring Boot** and **Maven** for the first time, and have been following [This tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/), with some modifications for what I need to do. I've finished the "Building a REST API" Section, and I want to run the application to make sure what I have so far actually works. When I try the command

```
mvn spring-boot:run -e >> output.txt
```

The build fails, and I get [the following output](http://pastebin.com/jerYGxTk), which for me is about five hundred lines of gibberish. Reading through this, I have no idea what's going wrong.

Pet.Java

```
package com.Me;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity

public class Pet {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

@JsonIgnore
public String name;
public String photo;
public String status;

public Pet(String name, String photo, String status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.status = status;
}

Pet() {

}
}
```

PetRepo.Java

```
package com.Me;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface PetRepo extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long> {
    Optional<Pet> findByName(String name);
    Optional<Pet> findByStatus (String status);
}
```

PetstoreApplication.Java

```
package com.Me;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PetstoreApplication {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(PetRepo petRepo) {
        return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(
                "jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
                .forEach(
                        a -> {
                            Pet pet = petRepo.save(new Pet(a, "meh", "Meh"));
                        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PetstoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{userId}/bookmarks")
class PetRestController {

    private final PetRepo petRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Pet getPet(@PathVariable Long petId) {
        return this.petRepo.findOne(petId);
    }

    @Autowired
    PetRestController(PetRepo petRepo){
        this.petRepo = petRepo;
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.Me</groupId>
<artifactId>petstore</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>petstore</name>
<description>Petstore Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm really not sure what's going on and would appreciate a hand with this issue.

Comment: This might help you. Compare with this repo and check what you are missing? https://github.com/joshlong/bookmarks/tree/tutorial/model/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the clue is at line 112. You haven't provided a database config so spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is trying to find an embedded one automatically and I don't see one being loaded in the listed dependencies. You haven't provided your pom.xml which would be useful but try adding the following dependency to it if you do not have something similar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.132</version>
</dependency>
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html section 29.1.1.

BTW In general when diagnosing issues such as this you want to look for the first exception reported and then for that exception look at the last (nearest the bottom) "Caused by" exception.

HTH

Comment: Just added my pom.xml. Nothing listed in there would fill the place of a database config, would it?

Comment: No database config would be configured as per other spring beans so you don't have any config. By adding the above dependency to your pom you make the H2 embedded database available on your classpath and spring-boot-data-jpa will automatically make use of it. There are possibly others that would work as well but H2 is the one that I use and I know it works automagically.

Comment: To clarify - configuring a database is a Spring concern and has nothing to do with Maven. If your database is external then you need to configure it in your Spring config. The reason that Maven gets involved is purely to make an embedded database **available** - it does not configure it - but because it has been made available on the classpath Spring Boot "sees" it and in the absence of any other configuration will automatically configure the embedded one. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give h2 a shot